# jQuery show/hide rows based on filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

**Preface:**

I am working on a function to allow a user to choose data points to filter a table by. Each table row has 3 attributes associated with it, `Title`, `Department`, and `Location`.

There are three multi-select filter options on the page that allow the user to narrow their search down by selecting 1 or more filter options by each of the fields.

As those options are selected, it triggers a function to adjust the table and only show the rows with data that matches their filter.

**The Problem:**

Since my function contains a loop that checks each of the filter options independently, its hiding/showing rows in order which is causing problems. For example if it was supposed to show the first row in the table because the filter told it to, the next filter says to only show rows that matches its filter, ignoring the ones before it.

**What I have Tried:**

I attempted to build the function in a way where it hides all the rows to start and then if the attribute of the table row was contained in our filter, it shows the row. This works for the first filter but as it iterates over the rows and hits the other filters, it hides them when it shouldn't be.

**Ideal Solution:**

Looking for a way to clean up this function where it applies the filter logic all at once and not in order by the function call. If I choose `Austin` as my location, it will show rows that have the attribute `location=austin`. If I then select a `department` in the filters, it needs to apply both the location and department filter to the table.

**Code Sample:**

```
// Filters our user groups based on selections
function filterUserGroups(){

  // Define our vars
  var locationsFilter = $('[name=in_ugLocationsFilter]').val(),
      departmentsFilter = $('[name=in_ugDepartmentsFilter]').val(),
      titlesFilter = $('[name=in_ugTitlesFilter]').val(),
      tempLocation = '',
      tempDepartment = '',
      tempTitle = '';

  // Loop over our rows and show the data that matches our filters
  $('[name=userGroupsRows] tr').hide();
  $('[name=userGroupsRows] tr').each(function(){

    // Get the current vars of each row
    tempLocation = $(this).data('location');
    tempDepartment = $(this).data('department');
    tempTitle = $(this).data('title');

    // Do we have any filter options selected?
    if(locationsFilter || departmentsFilter || titlesFilter){

      // If the location is in our filter, show row
      if(jQuery.inArray(tempLocation, locationsFilter) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }
      // If the departmentis in our filter, show row
      if(jQuery.inArray(tempDepartment, departmentsFilter) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }
      // If the title is in our filter, show row
      if(jQuery.inArray(tempTitle, titlesFilter) != -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/p4xvgLo1/1/

Comment: I'm guessing what you have is effectively an "or" between the filters and what you want is an "and"? Is that correct?

Comment: @Ouroborus Yeah that sounds right - couldn't think of a simple way to explain that.

Comment: Have you considered using https://datatables.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: Try with this:

```
var show = false;
if (locationsFilter) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(tempLocation, locationsFilter) != -1) {
    show = true;
  }
}
if (!show && departmentsFilter) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(tempDepartment, departmentsFilter) != -1) {
    show = true;
  }
}
if (!show && titlesFilter) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(tempTitle, titlesFilter) != -1) {
    show = true;
  }
}
if (show) $(this).show();
```

See the edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p4xvgLo1/7/

Comment: I tried this and selected `Austin` as the location and then both departments. I think it should show both rows in this case since it meets the criteria for the departments filter.

Comment: The problem you're facing is that the filter says `Austin2`, while the actual value is `Austin 2` with a space between.

Comment: Changing that still didn't work as expected unfortunately.

Comment: I checked your code again, you have the same problem for the other variables. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/p4xvgLo1/6/

Comment: This is what I am referring to: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2m3k5s7.jpg - This should show both rows since the departments is matching both attributes.

Comment: But the second row doesn't have `Austin` department but `Austin 2`... So you want it to show the rows that match any of the filters? If that's the case you should change your code to this: https://jsfiddle.net/p4xvgLo1/7/

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm sorry I didn't make that clear. It was set up like an `OR` statement in the beginning and wasn't working so I figured it needed to be changed. It would make sense to remain `OR` though since it needs to match multiple filters

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't understand you then. I changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you hide everything I would also add a check so that if all the filters are empty everything is shown `(locationsFilter==null && departmentsFilter==null && titlesFilter==null)` and then I'd change `data-department="Global Financial Services 2"` to not have a space so it's the same as the filter name: `data-department="Global Financial Services2"`.

```
if (locationsFilter || departmentsFilter || titlesFilter) {
    // If the location is in our filter, show row
    if (jQuery.inArray(tempLocation, locationsFilter) != -1 || (locationsFilter==null&&departmentsFilter==null&&titlesFilter==null)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
    // If the location is in our filter, show row
    if (jQuery.inArray(tempDepartment, departmentsFilter) != -1|| (locationsFilter==null&&departmentsFilter==null&&titlesFilter==null)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
    // If the location is in our filter, show row
    if (jQuery.inArray(tempTitle, titlesFilter) != -1|| (locationsFilter==null&&departmentsFilter==null&&titlesFilter==null)) {
      $(this).show();
    }
```

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3c3vjfhz/1/

Comment: This is close as well but when I selected Austin + Both Departments, its only showing one record. Anything with Austin should show as well as anything either either department selected.